# Regular expression how to replace the src link in img tag

Tags: java, regex

I tried many ways to do this. And I am totally new to Regular expression.
I want to replace all img src link to other link.

My html file just are like this:

```
<img src="01"></img><img src="02"></img><img src="03"></img>
```

or it would be like this:

```
<  img src  =  "01"></img><    img src="02"><    img src = "03"></img>
```

There might be space or just without "`</img>`"

and I want them be like this way:

```
<div><p><DIV class="a"><img src="01"></img></p></div><div><p><DIV class="a"><img src="02"></img></p></div><div><p><DIV class="a"><img src="03"></img></p></div>
```

and I use this to get the img src link:

```
            Pattern p = null;
            Matcher m = null;
            p = Pattern.compile("<img[^>]*src\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)");
            m = p.matcher(mystr);
            while (m.find()) {
                imgIDList.add(m.group(1));
            }
```

and I made the str list to replace:
ArrayList imgList4Replace = new ArrayList();

and I use this to excuse replace :

```
                mystr.replace(("<img[^>]*src\\s*=\\s*\""+imgListReplaceOriginal.get(nIndex)+"([^\"]*)"), imgList4Replace.get(nIndex)+"$2");
```

it just don't work. I've spent so much time to test.

And need your help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%5C%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%5C%29) method doesn't apply regex. You should use [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [replaceFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead

Comment: As a side note - images shouldn't have a closing tag. They should always be self closing: `<img src="whatever.jpg" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reliably use regexps with HTML/XML. You need an HTML parser, such as the confusingly named [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) (although it claims to be an HTML pretty-printer, it also gives you a DOM-view on your document)

Comment: I just want to make string and the string will be add to an html file. And this is for android webview, so .....

Comment: I don't think I can be any clearer. You can't reliably use regexps with HTML/XML!

Comment: he's right - look at that this epic piece and think about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags ;) - use xml tools and you're fine

Comment: Sorry,I think there is some misunderstanding about my question. Just forget the Html, just think I want to use regexps to change my string using java. I will try cubanacan's way, and let you know the result.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the link pagid sent to me. My fault. Sorry.

Comment: "You can't reliably use regexps with HTML/XML", why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class ImgTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            String s = "This is a sample<img src=\"test.html\" /> text";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[<](/)?img[^>]*[>]");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            if (m.find()) {
              String src = m.group();
              System.out.println(src);
            }
            s = s.replaceAll("[<](/)?img[^>]*[>]", "");
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
private static String replaceSrcs(String str, List<String> srcs) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<\\s*img\\s*src\\s*=\\s*\").*?(\"\\s*>)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int i = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "$1" + srcs.get(i++) + "$2");
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Now you need just invoke it:

```
replaceSrcs(mystr, imgList4Replace);
```

And it returns what you like.

Comment: Hi Cubanacan, thank you for your code, I tried and in my case, it seem don't work. I plan to report that to my boss, and change my way.

Comment: @AmyWuGo mentioned cases are successfully tested by this method. why not to upvote then.